# Uniform distribution [0,1) converted into {-1,1}

Tags: random

If i have a uniformly distributed random variable in [0,1), how can i modify it (only using arithmetic expressions) s.t. it is -1 with probability 1/2 and 1 with probability 1/2?

Comment: Why do you constrain yourself unnecessarily to only using arithmetic expressions?

Comment: Is this homework or an interview question?

Comment: Because I feel like I could have solved this questions easily 3 years ago :-)

Comment: @Juhana neither of it, i came along it while generating random cnf formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If floor (or conversion to nearest integer below x) is OK:

```
floor(x*2)*2-1
```

With rounding to the nearest integer:

```
round(x*2-0.5)*2-1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your random variable is less than 0.5, map it to -1, otherwise map it to 1.

Edit: If you allow using absolute value, you can do (x - 0.5) / abs(x - 0.5).

Comment: Oh, so just `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`?

Comment: Can you use integer division (so 1/3 = 0, for example)?

Comment: hmm, i would prefer without it

Comment: With abs, you could do (x - 0.5) / abs(x - 0.5).

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to get to an integer from an arbitrary real number, other than dividing by the number itself.